# Audit logging in mobile app

Tags: android, ios

I want to add the logging feature in my app, So that I can track the events happen in mobile to resolve the bug.

But I don't have any idea about the tools that are available.

Can anybody suggest me some tools or plugins for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean logging info during execution, so that you can track in development what is happening ? If so, I simply use `android.util.Log` and see in Android Studio/Android Monitor what's happening.

If you want to get crash reports from your users, you can use ACRA and get reports either by email or by reports to your server : https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Comment: No I want to create a audit log type of system. So I can track all the events happen on mobile from admin panel

Comment: I guess Loggly that @zed suggested is what you are looking for then.

Answer (score 2):

There are many available tools for crash-reporting feature:

1. [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/)
2. [Acra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)
3. [New Relic](https://newrelic.com)
4. [Instabug](https://instabug.com/)
5. [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/)
6. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

It is up to you and your preferences which should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Logging from Android logger (i.e. `Log.d`, `Log.e` and so on) cannot be read by applications anymore without triggering the permission through ADB.

Hence, you can use a logging service like [Loggly](http://loggly.com/). Install an Android library to log to Loggly, such as [Timber-Loggly](https://github.com/tony19/timber-loggly). You can then start logging.

To make it easier to log to all of your loggers, create a logging function such as:

```
public static function dLog(String message) {
       Log.d(TAG, message);
       Timber.d(message);
}
```

Or create an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) for crash reporting and realtime logging.
Code to log your message from the mobile:

```
Crashlytics.log(msg);
```